# Crashlytics found an invalid API key: @string/twitter_consumer_secret, when mofing from Crashreporting to Crashlytics in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I am in the process of migrating from firebase crash reporting to Firebase Crashlytics (as we have to until 9th September), following the guides here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-from-crash-reporting
and double checked I have no left over
I followed the guide here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0

I also searched around quiet a while, and found some similar questions, but no answer helped, or they are too old to apply, because they are pre Firebase versions.

when i do a "build/clean" in Android Studio, I get the following error

```
Crashlytics found an invalid API key: @string/twitter_consumer_secret. 
Check the Crashlytics plugin to make sure that the application has been added successfully! 
Contact support@fabric.io for assistance.
```

So I searched for the 'twitter_consumer_secret' in my whole project and for the word "twitter". The only spot it is found, is the generated Android Manifest in the build  path.

So I assume Crashlytics complains, because it does not find a valid key there.

But why is this 'twitter_consumer_secret' generated there ?

I have the following in the dependency's section

```
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // at the end of the gradle file
apply plugin: 'io.fabric' // at top of the gradle file after 'com.android.application'
```

I really hoped to get this done today, so any help is more then welcome.

To add:
If I only remove the

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

the error goes away, but Crashlytics does not seem to work.

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. I followed up via your email into our support channel.

Comment: Mike, looks like your email got lost. This might be due to my Google Drive run out of space, which also seems to block gmail from receiving. Which is shown on web login, but not in the APP. This should be fixed by now, apologize for that. May ask you to resend your message.

Comment: Hmm, I tried searching for the email and can't find it either. Can you email support(at)fabric(dot)io?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is in `com.google.gms`. Use version **`4.0.1`** instead of `4.1.0`:

### android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}
```

It should solve the issue.

Comment: I gave it a try, but got the same result. I will reach out to support, as I have no idea, why this API key gets build.

Comment: Note, that this should be in `android/build.gradle`, not in `android/app/build.gradle`. Also do not forget to remove your `implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'` line, clean cache and perform gradle sync.